# Angular 2 this.router.events.subscribe does not work on refresh or when url is typed in

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app written in Angular 2, the nav is supposed to look slightly different on each route.  I am listening for `NavigationEnd` using `this.router.events.subscribe`  It works fine when clicking links, but this method does not seem to be fired when the page is refreshed or when you type a route into the url bar.

This is part of my subscribe function:

```
subscribeToEvents() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        // see also 
        if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.getCompanyName();
            var rou = val.url.toLowerCase().trim();
            console.log("our route", rou);
            switch (rou) {
                case "/projectlist":
                    this.currentPage = "projects";
                    this.page = "Project List";
                    break;
```

I have tried console logging `this.router.url` to see what comes up and it just always console logs '/' when I refresh the page.

Comment: Are you losing the parameters in the url when you refresh?

Comment: Doing a hard reload (i.e. browser reload) breaks out of Angular routing. For Angular router to stay "in control" and be able to emit its events, you need to leave `index.html` loaded in your browser and let Angular handle the route changes.

Comment: What do mean by parameters inoabrian?
AngularFrance, I wasn't doing a hard reload it was just a normal refresh, but how would I accomplish leaving leave index.html loaded in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution,  I just added a timeout to the navbar's ng-init and then `this.router.url` gets the correct route.

```
      setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.router.url === '/projectlist') {
                this.currentPage = "projects";
                this.page = "Project List"
            } else if (this.router.url === '/dashboard') {
                this.currentPage = "dashboard";
                this.page = "Dashboard";
            } else if (this.router.url === '/equipmentlist') {
                this.currentPage = "equipment";
                this.page = "Equipment"
            } else if (this.router.url === '/recipelist') {
                   ... more routes ...
            } else {
                this.page = "Default";
            }
        }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `subscribeToEvents()` in your constructor. It will definitely solve your problem

Comment: What do you mean with `subscribeToEvents()`? Couldn't find any reference for this function

Comment: Agreed with Fabio.  This needs more information.  I can't find any reference for it either.

Answer (score 1):

The `navigationEnd` event has already been raised when the component registers for it under the parent/base component. This led the current component route instance not to publish another `navigationEnd` event. So the solution here is to explicitly start the subscription of the latest `navigationEnd` event by using the `startWith()` operator from the RxJs. i.e.

```
public myRouterObservable$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    startWith(this.router),
    map((navigationEnd: NavigationEnd) => {
      console.log('navigation end : ', navigationEnd.url);
    })
  );
```